# How to pipe a WriteStream concatenating an extension?

Tags: node.js, express, node-archiver

I am new in NodeJS. I know we can stream data to the client by using pipe() method.

Here is the snippet of the code

```
 router.get('/archive/*', function (req, res) {

        var decodedURI = decodeURI(req.url);
        var dirarr = decodedURI.split('/');
        var dirpath = path.join(dir, dirarr.slice(2).join("/"));
        console.log("dirpath: " + dirpath);
        var archive = archiver('zip', {
            zlib: {level: 9} // Sets the compression level.
        });
        archive.directory(dirpath, 'new-subdir');
        archive.on('error', function (err) {
            throw err;
        });
        archive.pipe(res)
        archive.on('finish', function () {
            console.log("finished zipping");
        });
        archive.finalize();

    });
```

when I use a get request the zipped file downloaded but  **without any extension**. I know its because I am piping a writestream into the response. Is there anyway  pipe it with a .zip extension ? Or How can I send the zip file without building the zip file in HDD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to change Headers before piping,

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
res.setHeader('Content-disposition' ,'attachment; filename=downlaod.zip');
```

For the Given Code,

```
router.get('/archive/*', function (req, res) {
        var decodedURI = decodeURI(req.url);
        var dirarr = decodedURI.split('/');
        var dirpath = path.join(dir, dirarr.slice(2).join("/"));
        var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/7.zip');
        var archive = archiver('zip', {
            zlib: {level: 9} // Sets the compression level.
        });
        archive.directory(dirpath, 'new-subdir');
        archive.on('error', function (err) {
            throw err;
        });
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition' ,'attachment; filename=downlaod.zip');
        archive.pipe(res);
        archive.finalize();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`res.attachment()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.attachment) to both set the filename of the download, and also its mime-type:

```
router.get('/archive/*', function (req, res) {
  res.attachment('archive.zip');
  ...
});
```

Comment: but I dont want to create the zip file in hdd. I just want to pipe the result from the archiver module as response

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked to carefully: all that `res.attachment` does it set HTTP headers.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Before sending the attachment change its content type and content disposition right ?

Comment: That's correct. In this case, the file would be downloaded with the suggested filename `archive.zip`, but you can change that, of course.

Comment: Thank You, I have posted the answer.